# How can I tell if a characteristic read is currently executing on a device using flutter_blue?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to know if there is a way to tell if a characteristic read is currently happening on a bluetooth device in flutter using flutter_blue. I have been getting errors that relate to a read being executed before another read can complete.

The reason I would like to have this option is because I periodically do reads in the background of my device using a timer and track them with an InheritedModel I created. However, in a child widget of this controller, I have the displaying of values and a button that lets the user do a write to the device. If I let the user do a write to the device, I want to be able to verify I can do a write operation without causing a read_characteristic_error.

So far I do the periodic checking asynchronously within a widget that I basically use as a controller whose only purpose is to update the device. This widget isn't an inherited widget but it returns my inheritedModel that has the values I depend on.

Please note the microcontroller I communicate with is a BLE device, so if a plugin solution is suggested it needs to be BLE compatible.

Answer (score 0):

My current work around for this is to pass two functions from my parent widget 
to the child widget that can stop and start the timer that controls my periodic reading. I stop the timer when I'm about to do my write action 
and start it after I've handled the write action for the characteristics.